# Possible option for PrimayKey in Table creation with KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've started working with `KSQL` and quite living the experience. I'm trying to work with Table and Stream join and the scenario is as below.
I have a sample data set like this:

```
"0117440512","0134217727","US","United States","VIRGINIA","Vienna","DoD Network Information Center"
"0134217728","0150994943","US","United States","MASSACHUSETTS","Woburn","Genuity"
```

in my kafka topic-1. Is a static data set loaded to Table and might get updated once in a month or so.

I have one more data set like:

```
{"state":"AD","id":"020","city":"Andorra","port":"02","region":"Canillo"}
{"state":"GD","id":"024","city":"Arab","port":"29","region":"Ordino"}
```

in kafka topic-2. Is a stream of data being loaded to streams.

Since `Table` cant be created without specifying the Key, my data don't have a unique column to do so. So while loading data from topic-1 to Table, what exactly should my key be? Remember my Table might get populated/updated once in a month or so with same data and new once too. With new data being loaded I can replace them with the key.

I tried to find if there's something like incremental value as we call `PrimaryKey` in SQL, but didn't find any.

Can someone help me in correcting my approach towards the implementation or a query to create a `PrimaryKey` if exists. Thanks

Comment: OK let's back up a bit here. You need a key for your data, and you want to auto-generate one. What kind of data are you working with? If you want an auto incrementing key then it sounds like you want to treat every message as unique, which is what a KSQL _Stream_ is, not _Table_.

Comment: Yup that's right. I'm working with IP2location database. I load the data into a topic then to a table as its static. While my streams have a dynamic data performs a join on table for some info. That said, I would update my table once in a while.

Comment: Please correct me if my approach/understanding is not good. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with a clear example of your source(s) of data, and what processing you're trying to do with it?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Done. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I'm still not clear. You've shown two sets of data, but no context about the business question/model around them which would answer how we treat it in KSQL. If it's easier to discuss then head to http://cnfl.io/slack and the #ksql channel

Comment: @RobinMoffatt That's awesome platform, a reference manual all at once. Thanks for suggesting/inviting.

Answer (score 0):

No, KSQL doesn't have the concept of a self-incrementing key. You have to define the key when you produce the data into the topic on which the KSQL Table is defined.

--- EDIT

If you want to set the key on a message as it's ingested through Kafka Connect you can use Single Message Transform (SMT).

```
            "transforms":"createKey,extractInt",
            "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
            "transforms.createKey.fields":"id",
            "transforms.extractInt.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
            "transforms.extractInt.field":"id"
```

[See here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector#setting-kafka-message-key) for more details.

Comment: In that case, as mentioned is there a way to define the key in case of kafka-connect. OR should I have UDAF work in this case?

Comment: Well, this looks like a configuration while a key is picked from one of the values and not an incremental number by itself. Am I right? Please correct me. Thank you.